# Unresolved reference: box_one_text

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyEzQ.png)

I am not understanding the issue and I expect someone please help me all the objects are declared in the XML file but I can't understand the issue
I have tried many ways to resolve the issue but the issue is not getting resolved, I have tried creating the box_one_text elements many times and tried different kinds of "listof" many times.

```
package com.example.colormyviews

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity)

        setListeners()
    }

    private fun setListeners() {
        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text, box_four_text, box_five_text)

        for (item in clickableViews) {
            item.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun makeColored(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
            R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)
            R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_one_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_one"
        android:textColor="#039BE5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_two_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_two"
        android:textColor="#039BE5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_one_text"
        tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_three_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_three"
        android:textColor="#039BE5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_four_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box_two_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_four_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_four"
        android:textColor="#039BE5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_five_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_three_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_five_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_five"
        android:textColor="#039BE5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_four_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **findViewById**.
For instance:

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.box_one_text)
```